# Flask ignores .htaccess file

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, flask, mod-wsgi

I have a page being served by my Flask app that is supposed to have access restricted via an .htaccess file. I know that I have Apache and the .htaccess file configured correctly because it's working correctly for a .php file in the same directory. Does Flask (or mod-wsgi) need to be configured a certain way to use .htaccess?

In my `.conf` file, I have the following

```
WSGIDaemonProcess main_proc processes=8 python-home=/var/www/html/venv
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/html>
    WSGIProcessGroup main_proc
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    AllowOverride All

    AuthType shibboleth                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1                                                                                                                                                                                                
    Require shib-session                                                                                                                                                                                                               
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `.htaccess` file in the directory, you can insert the same code in the apache configuration. First, you'll need to enable the htaccess by overriding the Directory directive.

```
<Directory /var/www/flask_app>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then enabling the rewrite mod and restarting the apache,

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You can add the htaccess code in apache configuration file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# (Requires Apache 2.4.8+)
RewriteOptions InheritDown

RewriteRule ^/index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/. /index.html [L]
```

Notice here, the `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required. And `RewriteBase`  is not valid in the server context. We'll need to use lookahead `(LA-U:)` to retrieve the filename the request is mapped to.

Comment: Putting ```Order allow, deny``` in my ```.conf``` file caused an error

Comment: Try removing the space before deny: `Order allow,deny`. Order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or 'mutual-failure'